# Update JPanel by replacing another JPanel in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I'm using the NetBeans GUI to develop a graphical interface for my application.
In summary, I have a JTabbedPane inside of a JFrame, simply described as:

```
public class MyApplication extends JFrame(){


    private JTabbedPane tabbedpanel_tasks;
    private JPanel jpanel_father;

    ...

    // Settings of JTabbedPane

    tabbedpanel_tasks = new JTabbedPane();

    tabbedpanel_tasks.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);

    tabbedpanel_tasks.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    jpanel_father = new JPanel();

    ...

}
```

I have a specific JPanel - I'll call jpanel_father - which is one of the several JPanels that compose JTabbedPane:

```
public class MyApplication extends JFrame(){

    ...
    // Initializing a new JPanel and inserting into JTabbedPane

    jpanel_father = new JPanel();
    tabbedpanel_tasks.addTab("Father tab", jpanel_father);

    ...

}
```

Looking into jpanel_father, there is a JComboBox (combobox) and a JPanel (jpanel_generic), which is supposed to assume a particular JPanel extended class, created as a JPanel Form of NetBeans. The combobox stores 2 values, meaning that when I select one of them, the associated JPanel will appear at jpanel_generic's place (showed in the code below):

```
public class MyApplication extends JFrame(){

    private JComboBox combobox;
    private JPanel jpanel_generic;
    private JPanelSon1 jpanel_son1;
    private JPanelSon2 jpanel_son2;

    ...

    // Code block for constructing jpanel_father
    combobox = new JComboBox(new String[] { "JPanel 1", "JPanel 2" });
    jpanel_generic = new JPanel();
    jpanel_son1 = new JPanelSon1();
    jpanel_son2 = new JPanelSon2();

    combobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int option = combobox.getSelectedIndex();

            setCurrentGenericPanel(option);

        }
});

    jpanel_father.add(combobox);
    jpanel_father.add(jpanel_generic);
    jpanel_father.setSize(300,300);
    jpanel_father.setVisible(true);
}

public void setCurrentGenericPanel(int option){

    jpanel_generic.removeAll();

    if(option == 0)
       jpanel_generic = jpanel_son1;
    else
       jpanel_generic = jpanel_son2;

    jpanel_generic.validate();
    jpanel_generic.repaint();

}


public class JPanelSon1 extends JPanel {

    private JLabel labelson1;

    public JPanelSon1(){

        labelson1 = new JLabel("This is JPanel Son 1");
        add(labelson1);
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}

public class JPanelSon2 extends JPanel {

    private JLabel labelson2;

    public JPanelSon2(){

        labelson2 = new JLabel("This is JPanel Son 2");
        add(labelson2);
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

However, when I select a value on combobox, nothing happens. I mean... the panel_generic is not updated with the respective correct JPanel. What is probably wrong in my code? I apologize for omitting details like imports, middle-code etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't apologise about omitting code... if you add irrelevant code your post will be downvoted and ignored - The important thing is always to add a *minimal example* of the exact part of the code where a problem lies.

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
public void setCurrentGenericPanel(int option){    
    jpanel_generic.removeAll();    
    if(option == 0)
       jpanel_generic = jpanel_son1;
    else
       jpanel_generic = jpanel_son2;

    jpanel_generic.validate();
    jpanel_generic.repaint();

}
```

With the `jpanel_generic.removeAll();` method call you are removing all components **from** the generic JPanel with the `removalAll()` method. You are not removing the jpanel_generic JPanel from its container, which I believe was your goal with this call.

Also, changing the variable referred to by the jpanel_generic variable does not swap the object that is displayed in the GUI. This issue boils down to the very large difference between what an object is and what a variable is. To do what you're trying to do manually,  you would remove all components from the JPanel container that **holds** the jpanel_generic JPanel, then add the new component to this same container, then revalidate and repaint that **container**.

But instead of messing with all that, I suggest a much simpler solution, that the container JPanel use a CardLayout, and that you use that layout to swap JPanels. Google `Java CardLayout Tutorial`. First Google hit for the gory details.